# IOMMU Support Unraid

Tags: cpu

Ive search high and low, can't find anything on this. I'm trying to setup a UNRAID build using at Core-i7-980X Extreme. I have VT-x turned on via the BIOS. In the setup/video tutorial for Virtual Machines on UNRAID, it says to turn on IOMMU. I can't for the life of me find out where this is, or if my chip supports it. Any advice would be much appreciated.

**Core-i7-980X Extreme** - 
http://ark.intel.com/products/47932/Intel-Core-i7-980X-rocessor-Extreme-Edition-12M-Cache-3_33-GHz-6_40-GTs-Intel-QPI

**Full Specs**

**Processor**: Intel i7-980X Extreme

**Motherboard**: EVGA X58 FTW3

**RAM** - OCZ Reaper Edition 24GB -  DDR3 1333 (PC3 10666)

**Powersupply** - BFG EX Series 1000w

**Graphics Card** - PNY Quadro 4000

Comment: Is VT-d turned on? (not just VT-x aka 'virtualisation') but VT-d for device passthough using an IOMMU).

Comment: I only see  Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x). I dont see an option for VT-d. I would post a screenshot but its creating a parity right now. I'll post once it's done

Comment: It might not support it. Wikipedia list it as default on for Lynnfield and later (but your i7 is a first gem Bloomfield).  And searching on ark with  filter for VT-d supported and socket 1366 lists the Xeon versions of 1366, but not the consumer i7...

Sources:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i7_microprocessors  
http://ark.intel.com/search/advanced?s=t&SocketsSupported=FCLGA1366&VTD=true

Comment: bummer. thanks for looking into it. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I have  similar era motherboard with an i7-920 and IIRC the manual did claim vt-d. That means that a second hand Xeon might work. Cheapter said than done though, upgrading a 920 is afforable, a similar 980 is still expensive.

Comment: Thought about this a lot last night, any ideas/suggestions on how to keep all the hardware in tact but just upgrade the processor? I would have to find a processor that is compatible with my board but not exactly sure how to do that since it's and older model.

Comment: @Hennes are you saying that something like this would work?

https://www.amazon.com/Intel-Processor-2-66GHz-LGA1366-BX80601920/dp/B001H5T7LK

Comment: Or maybe a http://www.ebay.com/itm/Intel-E5-2650-v1-SR0KQ-2Ghz-8-core-C2-VMware-OK-95W-Socket-LGA-2011-Xeon-CPU-S2-/142140541899?hash=item21183c8bcb:g:u4kAAOSw9IpX0Z1n

Comment: First link is to an i920 which is the same as you have execpt slower and fewer cores. Nu VT-d. The second on is for socket 2011. That one will not work at all.  Best is to check the motherboard manual or manufcaturers website for compatible CPU. If those are unavailable google/ebay for one of the CPUs listed in my ark.intel list. Some of those will work, some may not (not all will be in the motherboards BIOS).

Comment: I've been doing some digging, my mother board says it supports "CPU Socket 1366". I'm assuming if I can find a chip that supprots socket 1366 it will work? Found this one https://www.amazon.com/Intel-i7-950-Socket-LGA1366-Processor/dp/B002A6G3V2

Comment: No, not any chip. Any chip with the right TPD and which is supported by the motherboards firmware (aka BIOS). Which means looking though the website of your motherboard manufacturer and reading the list of supported CPU's. That may be all socket 1366 CPU's, or it could be a subset of them.

Comment: I'm with you Hennes, thanks for the response. The i7-950 supports VT-x and EPT. The ram I have is  DDR3 1333. Per intel it says it support "DDR3 800/1066 " Do I need to buy new RAM that is 800/1066? Or will 1333 work? Again, I'm trying to invest as little as possible to get virtualization working with the parts I have. I'm learning a lot from this conversation, thanks you again.

Comment: No need for new RAM. Think of it as a car with a top speed of 133kmph. It also runs fine at 106kmph or 80kmph.

Comment: I added the full specs of the box above

Would this one work for Virtualization?
https://www.amazon.com/Intel-i7-950-Socket-LGA1366-Processor/dp/B002A6G3V2